# Mysql update fields with random sentence

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way i can update database rows with random sentences so that all field of row will be different.

for example the fields value will be different:

Pellentesque vel accumsan ex.

Vestibulum vulputate sodales ligula, ut tincidunt nulla luctus et.

Nam pretium et ante at dapibus. Suspendisse lacinia accumsan nisi vel posuere.

etc.

Comment: unclear what you asking?

Comment: Are you trying to get dirty someone's DB?

Comment: yes you can insert randomized data ... just write a function to do this

Comment: From phpmyadmin i want to do this @donald123

Comment: suppose there are 100 rows in a table. I want to run a single query so that title fields will be updated with the random sentence and all fields value will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$values = array();

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `tabel_name` (`word`) VALUES ";

$total_rows = 100;

while ($total_rows) {
    $random_sentence = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
    $values[] = "('$random_sentence')";

    $total_rows--;
}

$insert_query .= implode(', ', $values);
```

Edit:

Here is only `MySQL`

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (concat(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand()*36+1, 1),
             ( substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand()*36+1, 1)),
            (  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand()*36+1, 1)),
             ( substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand()*36+1, 1)),
             ( substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', rand()*36+1, 1))
```

Note there is no guarantee of uniqueness. You'll have to check for that separately.

Comment: suppose there are 100 rows in a table. I want to run a single query so that title fields will be updated with the random sentence and all fields value will be different.

Comment: no, i need a mysql query, not php scripting. @umair

Comment: thanks @Umair, this helps me out. required minimal changes.

Comment: Wont you pls accept my asnswer :P ?